# I want to transfer data from notepad to listview

Tags: c#, listview

I have a project that creates folders and inside those folder new text files are created with some content inside.

It creates text files like this:

```
versionname: 1.3.2
$
explanation:"something that we type in program"
$
date:14.07.2016
```

I want to create a listview and 3 columns and I want version name, explanation and date loaded into those columns and type there every time I start my program
adding folder and code is like this:

PS: I am not using date table because I don't want to

Thanks for your attention

```
string klasor = textBox1.Text;

Directory.CreateDirectory("C:/Users/user/Desktop/");
Directory.CreateDirectory("C:/Users/user/Desktop/proje/Versiyonlar/"+klasor);

//string Dizinpath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
StreamWriter Dosya1=File.CreateText("C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\proje\\Versiyonlar\\"+klasor+"\\"+klasor+".txt");
Dosya1.Close();

StreamWriter SW = new StreamWriter("C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\proje\\Versiyonlar\\"+klasor+"\\"+klasor+".txt");
SW.WriteLine("Versiyon no:" + textBox1.Text);
SW.WriteLine("$");
SW.WriteLine("Açıklama:"+textBox2.Text);
SW.WriteLine("$");
SW.WriteLine("Eklenme tarihi:"+dateTimePicker1.Text);
SW.Close();

MessageBox.Show("Versiyon ve açıklama eklendi");
```

This is the code for adding folder and txt file now I want to add that txt files information to the listview

Comment: Code is not uploaded. Please have a look

Comment: it is not really clear what you have problems with. Do you want to read the files or do you want to capture the written text inside "notepad" ?

Comment: i want to capture what inside and show in listview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 listView1.View = View.Details;
        listView1.Columns.Add("Versiyon No", 133, HorizontalAlignment.Left);
        listView1.Columns.Add("Açıklama", 240, HorizontalAlignment.Left);
        listView1.Columns.Add("Tarih", 150, HorizontalAlignment.Left);

        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\proje\\Versiyonlar\\1.1.2\\" + "1.1.2.txt", Encoding.Default))
            {
            string line;
            while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                int sira = listView1.Items.Count;


                listView1.Items.Add(line.Split(',')[0]);
                listView1.Items[sira].SubItems.Add(line.Split(',')[1]);
                listView1.Items[sira].SubItems.Add(line.Split(',')[2]);
                listView1.Items[sira].SubItems.Add(line.Split(',')[3]);
                listView1.Items[sira].SubItems.Add(line.Split(',')[4]);

            }

        }
```

i think i just solved question like this